# How to add font awesome icons inside select options?

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I want to add some fontawesome icons  to status of user when is active or inactive... etc. I am trying with this code:

```
    <td>
    <select class="statusSelect" data id="{{$user->id}}">

    <option {{getStatus($user->status) == 'Active' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="a">
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle text danger"></i>
    <strong> {{__('home.active')}} </strong> 
    </option>

    <option {{getStatus($user->status) == 'Wait' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="w">
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle text-warning"> </i>
    <strong> {{__('home.wait')}} </strong>
    </option>

    <option {{getStatus($user->status) == 'Banned' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="b">
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle text-danger"> </i>
    <strong> {{__('home.ban')}} </strong>
    </option>

    </select>
    </td>
```

I also read [this](http://thewebfosters.com/add-icons-html-select-options/) but doesn't work in my case.

Comment: What's your `fa` version? Change class `fa` to `fas` , look like this `<i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>` look here https://fontawesome.com/icons/minus-circle?style=solid

Answer (score 1):

Html option tag's permitted content is only [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option). You are trying to adding html content inside option tag. That's why browser clears what you inserted.

In blog post which you shared, it works with JavaScript. It reads option's `data-` attribute and replace(or wrap and hide.) `<select>` (which contains options) with custom html structure it looks like select component but not really is.

You can create your custom selectbox with JavaScript or find dozens examples in web.

Check this out: https://thdoan.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

what font-awesome version did you use? and did you try with the data-content attribute? cause using “data-content” attribute we can insert custom HTML into the options such as font-awesome tags.

Maybe like this code:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-address-book-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>Option1"></option>
  <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-calculator' aria-hidden='true'></i>Option2"></option>
  <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-heart' aria-hidden='true'></i>Option3"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Tried this, but doesn't work. At least not in combination with Vue3